# Saving dynamically added rows in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, rows

I have a form with dynamically added rows. It works. After filling form fields and click on submit button "check correctness", validation is preformed. If the data are wrong it needs a correct. If data are correct we get a new submit button "generate pdf" for generated PDF files. After data validating the data entering by user should be still visible. It works too in my form.

The problem is when I add some rows. After filling its and click on submit "check correctness" the new added rows are disappearing with its data. Do anybody knows how can I save this rows after validate?

This is my HTML code for dynamically added fields:

```
    $oForm->formHTML('<div class="add_btn_block" style="margin-left:200px;"><div class="row_add_btn add_row">title</div></div>');
       $oForm->formHTML(addRows2());

   function addRows(){
        $personsArray = $_POST['persons'];
        $html = '
        <table id="template2" style="display:none; ">
            <tr id="row_{0}">
                <td><input type="text" name="persons[]"></td>
                <td><img src="/../_img/row_del.png" id="delete_{0}" alt="usun"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table id="list2">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
               <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="persons[]" value="'.$personsArray[1].'"></td>
                    <td></td>
               </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" id="app_here2"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>';
            return $html;
    }
```

And this is JavaScript code for that.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var i = 2;
            var rowTemplate2 = jQuery.format($("#template2").html());

            function addRow(){
                var ii = i++;
                $("#app_here2").append(rowTemplate2(ii));
                $("#delete_" + ii).click(function(){
                    $("#row_" + ii).remove();
                });
            }
            $(".add_row").click(addRow);
        });
</script>
```

This is some PHP:

```
if($_POST["ACT"] == NULL){
    $oForm->formInput(array(
        'type'=>'hidden',
        'name'=>'ACT',
    ));

    $oForm->formInput(array(
        'id' =>'counter',
        'type'=>'hidden',
        'name'=>'counter',
        'value'=>0));

    $oForm->formSubmit(array(
        'name' => 'sprawdzPoprawnosc',
        'value' => 'check correctness'
    ));
}
```

There is some screens:

1. Its single row:
   1[image]

2.It's after adding two rows. I want after page refreshing still have form like this(3 rows and data into its):
[image]

3.It's how it look like now, after page refreshing:
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: assuming you're doing a full-blown round-trip to the server and back with the form, e.g. completely rebuilding the page, then your page rebuild would have to include any added rows at that time as well. otherwise you'll just be back to where you started.

Comment: Hi there. The community has discussed the question "should we use home-made tag devices in titles", and it has been decided that we should not (it's at _Meta_ if you're interested). If you could avoid writing titles that way, it helps reduce further editing work - thanks.

Comment: You're right @Marc B but how can i do it? I should make a loop to save data from form but i don't know exacly how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Marc B.  You would have to store the changes to the form before it comes back to the page from the server.  One option would be to store it in a temporary file, or database.  I think this would work, but might be overkill.  I would try storing it in a $_SESSION variable, so when the server goes to send the new form, it can get it from that specific $_SESSION variable, if it exists.